# Hue url is not opening

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, hue

I recently started using Hue in ubuntu(16.04). When I am running in local system it is opening successfully. But when the same process used by my server it is not opening i mean with server IP and port number.Is there any firewall issue for opening port 8888 as in hue.ini config file or should I give permissions to the particular port to open hue UI.

Can anyone suggest how to configure hue server configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind hue application server address as the ip address.

Do you check this article ?

- [How to bind http_host to 0.0.0.0 in hue.ini ?](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/How-to-bind-http-host-to-0-0-0-0-in-hue-ini/td-p/30147)